# State variables not updating and I so not know why ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call the method 'call(index)' in the code below.  I have set the state from  the props inside getDerivedStateFromProps.  However, when I try to use the state variable inside componentDidMount(), this variable is undefined and I do not understand why.  The props def contains data as it prints out the state variable that I need inside render().

```
class ItemDetails extends Component {

state = {
    initData: {},
    stoneData: {},
    stoneSupply: {}
}


async call (index) {
    console.log('call.index: ' + index);
    try {
        const supply = await getSupplyInfoForStoneType(index);
        this.setState({
            stoneSupply: supply
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    if (props.stoneData.id !== state.stoneData.id){
        return {
            stoneData: props.stoneData
        }
    }else{
        return null
    } 
}


async componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount()');
    this.setState({
        initData: initData
    })

    console.log('this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id);
    this.call(this.state.stoneData.id);
}






render() {
    console.log('render.this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id);

    return (
            ......
}
}

export default ItemDetails;
```

console.log('this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id):

```
undefined
```

console.log('render.this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id):

```
1 // which is correct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 5 years working with React I've yet to find a compelling case for using `getDerivedStateFromProps` function. Why not just `this.call(this.props.stoneData.id);` in `componentDidMount`? It's anti-pattern to store passed props in local state in React anyway, so this is actually the preferred use.

```
class ItemDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    initData: {},
    stoneData: {},
    stoneSupply: {}
  }

  async call (index) {
    console.log('call.index: ' + index);
    try {
      const supply = await getSupplyInfoForStoneType(index);
      this.setState({
        stoneSupply: supply
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount()');
    this.setState({
      initData: initData,
      stoneData: this.props.stoneData, // if you must
    })

    this.call(this.props.stoneData.id);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render.this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id);

    return ( ...... );
  }
}

export default ItemDetails;
```

Answer (score 0):

setState will be batched in react. You will not get the current value until the state is updated.

> [React state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

By the time `console.log('this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id)` the `this.state.stoneData` is not updated yet. Everytime when a  state changes , react will trigger a re-render which calls the **render** method that is why you're getting the latest state in  `console.log('render.this.state.stoneData.id: ' + this.state.stoneData.id)`

You can use **componentDidUpdate** to compare the previous and current props/state.It will trigger everytime when a state/prop changes

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
        if (this.state.stoneData.id !== prevState.stoneData.id){
           //caution : will call everytime stoneData.id changes, not only on mount
           this.call(this.state.stoneData.id);
        }
}
```

But I would suggest you to drop the `getDerivedStateFromProps` and change the `this.call(this.state.stoneData.id)` to `this.call(this.props.stoneData.id)`